I am running into an `Undefined symbol` issue with dart-ffi and Go
I am trying to use ffigen to develop a library that I can use to call a go package from dart code.
My current approach is to use the basic setup that you get from running the initial ffigen
flutter create --template=plugin_ffi \
  --platforms=android,ios,linux,macos,windows project_name

I am compiling my go code(CGO) to generate a header file that I then pull into the basic header file provided by running the initial ffigen creation script and use in the C code from the initial basic setup.
Whenever I do this, I get the error Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _parse_data
Here is my Go code that generates the header file:
//main.go

package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"
import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "strings"

    "github.com/erh/gonmea/analyzer"
)

//export parse_data
func parse_data(byteArr []byte) *C.char {
    fmt.Println(string(byteArr))
    in := io.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(byteArr))
    defer in.Close()

    parser, err := analyzer.NewParser()
    if err != nil {

        return C.CString(fmt.Sprintf("Error: %v", err))
    }

    reader := bufio.NewReader(in)
    for {
        line, _, err := reader.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
            if errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
                return nil
            }
            return C.CString(fmt.Sprintf("Error: %v", err))
        }
        line = []byte(strings.TrimSpace(string(line)))
        if len(line) == 0 {
            continue
        }
        msg, err := parser.ParseMessage(line)
        if err != nil {
            return C.CString(fmt.Sprintf("Error: %v", err))
        }
        md, err := json.MarshalIndent(msg, "", "  ")
        if err != nil {
            return C.CString(fmt.Sprintf("Error: %v", err))
        }
        fmt.Println(string(md))
        return C.CString(string(md))
    }
}

func main() {}


Here is the header file generated by the go code
/* Code generated by cmd/cgo; DO NOT EDIT. */

/* package command-line-arguments */


#line 1 "cgo-builtin-export-prolog"

#include <stddef.h>

#ifndef GO_CGO_EXPORT_PROLOGUE_H
#define GO_CGO_EXPORT_PROLOGUE_H

#ifndef GO_CGO_GOSTRING_TYPEDEF
typedef struct { const char *p; ptrdiff_t n; } _GoString_;
#endif

#endif

/* Start of preamble from import "C" comments.  */


#line 3 "main.go"

#include <stdlib.h>

#line 1 "cgo-generated-wrapper"


/* End of preamble from import "C" comments.  */


/* Start of boilerplate cgo prologue.  */
#line 1 "cgo-gcc-export-header-prolog"

#ifndef GO_CGO_PROLOGUE_H
#define GO_CGO_PROLOGUE_H

typedef signed char GoInt8;
typedef unsigned char GoUint8;
typedef short GoInt16;
typedef unsigned short GoUint16;
typedef int GoInt32;
typedef unsigned int GoUint32;
typedef long long GoInt64;
typedef unsigned long long GoUint64;
typedef GoInt64 GoInt;
typedef GoUint64 GoUint;
typedef size_t GoUintptr;
typedef float GoFloat32;
typedef double GoFloat64;
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <complex.h>
typedef _Fcomplex GoComplex64;
typedef _Dcomplex GoComplex128;
#else
typedef float _Complex GoComplex64;
typedef double _Complex GoComplex128;
#endif

/*
  static assertion to make sure the file is being used on architecture
  at least with matching size of GoInt.
*/
typedef char _check_for_64_bit_pointer_matching_GoInt[sizeof(void*)==64/8 ? 1:-1];

#ifndef GO_CGO_GOSTRING_TYPEDEF
typedef _GoString_ GoString;
#endif
typedef void *GoMap;
typedef void *GoChan;
typedef struct { void *t; void *v; } GoInterface;
typedef struct { void *data; GoInt len; GoInt cap; } GoSlice;

#endif

/* End of boilerplate cgo prologue.  */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern char* parse_data(GoSlice byteArr);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


Here is the header file generated from running the initial ffigen creation script
#ifndef GONMEA_FLUTTER_H
#define GONMEA_FLUTTER_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "libgonmea_flutter.h"

#if _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#if _WIN32
#define FFI_PLUGIN_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FFI_PLUGIN_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default"))) __attribute__((used))
#endif

// A very short-lived native function.
FFI_PLUGIN_EXPORT intptr_t sum(intptr_t a, intptr_t b);

extern char* parse_data(GoSlice byteArr);

FFI_PLUGIN_EXPORT char* parse_data_wrapper(GoSlice byteArr);

#endif

Here is the C code
#include "gonmea_flutter.h"

FFI_PLUGIN_EXPORT intptr_t sum(intptr_t a, intptr_t b) { 
    return a + b; 
}

FFI_PLUGIN_EXPORT char* parse_data_wrapper(GoSlice byteArr) {
    return parse_data(byteArr);
}

Here is my ffigen.yaml file
# Run with `flutter pub run ffigen --config ffigen.yaml`.
name: GonmeaFlutterBindings
description: |
  Bindings for `src/gonmea_flutter.h`.

  Regenerate bindings with `flutter pub run ffigen --config ffigen.yaml`.
output: 'lib/gonmea_flutter_bindings_generated.dart'
headers:
  entry-points:
    - 'src/gonmea_flutter.h'
  include-directives:
    - 'src/gonmea_flutter.h'
    - 'src/libgonmea_flutter.h'
preamble: |
  // ignore_for_file: always_specify_types
  // ignore_for_file: camel_case_types
  // ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names
comments:
  style: any
  length: full


Here is the autogenerated dart-ffi bindings generated by running  flutter pub run ffigen --config ffigen.yaml
// ignore_for_file: always_specify_types
// ignore_for_file: camel_case_types
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names

// AUTO GENERATED FILE, DO NOT EDIT.
//
// Generated by `package:ffigen`.
// ignore_for_file: type=lint
import 'dart:ffi' as ffi;

/// Bindings for `src/gonmea_flutter.h`.
///
/// Regenerate bindings with `flutter pub run ffigen --config ffigen.yaml`.
///
class GonmeaFlutterBindings {
  /// Holds the symbol lookup function.
  final ffi.Pointer<T> Function<T extends ffi.NativeType>(String symbolName)
      _lookup;

  /// The symbols are looked up in [dynamicLibrary].
  GonmeaFlutterBindings(ffi.DynamicLibrary dynamicLibrary)
      : _lookup = dynamicLibrary.lookup;

  /// The symbols are looked up with [lookup].
  GonmeaFlutterBindings.fromLookup(
      ffi.Pointer<T> Function<T extends ffi.NativeType>(String symbolName)
          lookup)
      : _lookup = lookup;

  ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char> parse_data(
    GoSlice byteArr,
  ) {
    return _parse_data(
      byteArr,
    );
  }

  late final _parse_dataPtr =
      _lookup<ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char> Function(GoSlice)>>(
          'parse_data');
  late final _parse_data =
      _parse_dataPtr.asFunction<ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char> Function(GoSlice)>();

  /// A very short-lived native function.
  int sum(
    int a,
    int b,
  ) {
    return _sum(
      a,
      b,
    );
  }

  late final _sumPtr =
      _lookup<ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.IntPtr Function(ffi.IntPtr, ffi.IntPtr)>>(
          'sum');
  late final _sum = _sumPtr.asFunction<int Function(int, int)>();

  ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char> parse_data_wrapper(
    GoSlice byteArr,
  ) {
    return _parse_data_wrapper(
      byteArr,
    );
  }

  late final _parse_data_wrapperPtr =
      _lookup<ffi.NativeFunction<ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char> Function(GoSlice)>>(
          'parse_data_wrapper');
  late final _parse_data_wrapper = _parse_data_wrapperPtr
      .asFunction<ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char> Function(GoSlice)>();
}

final class _GoString_ extends ffi.Struct {
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Char> p;

  @ptrdiff_t()
  external int n;
}

typedef ptrdiff_t = __darwin_ptrdiff_t;
typedef __darwin_ptrdiff_t = ffi.Long;

final class GoInterface extends ffi.Struct {
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> t;

  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> v;
}

final class GoSlice extends ffi.Struct {
  external ffi.Pointer<ffi.Void> data;

  @GoInt()
  external int len;

  @GoInt()
  external int cap;
}

typedef GoInt = GoInt64;
typedef GoInt64 = ffi.LongLong;


Finally, here is my implementation where I called the auto generated ffi bindings

import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

import 'gonmea_flutter_bindings_generated.dart';

/// A very short-lived native function.
///
/// For very short-lived functions, it is fine to call them on the main isolate.
/// They will block the Dart execution while running the native function, so
/// only do this for native functions which are guaranteed to be short-lived.
int sum(int a, int b) => _bindings.sum(a, b);


String? _processDataHelper(Uint8List data) {
  final rawDataPtr = calloc<Uint8>(data.length);
  final rawDataList = rawDataPtr.asTypedList(data.length);
  rawDataList.setAll(0, data);

  final goSlicePtr = calloc<GoSlice>();
  goSlicePtr.ref.data = rawDataPtr.cast<Void>();
  goSlicePtr.ref.len = data.length;
  goSlicePtr.ref.cap = data.length;

  final resultPtr = _bindings.parse_data_wrapper(goSlicePtr.ref);

  String? result;
  if (resultPtr != nullptr) {
    result = resultPtr.cast<Utf8>().toDartString();
    calloc.free(resultPtr.cast<Void>());
  }

  // Free remaining allocated memory
  calloc.free(goSlicePtr);
  calloc.free(rawDataPtr);

  return result;
}

Map<dynamic, dynamic> _stringToMap(String dartString) {
  try {
    final jsonString = json.decode(dartString);
    return jsonString;
  } catch (e) {
    return {};
  }
}

Map<dynamic, dynamic> processData(Uint8List data) {
  final readingsString = _processDataHelper(data);
  if (readingsString != null) {
    return _stringToMap(readingsString);
  }
  return {};
}



const String _libName = 'gonmea_flutter';

/// The dynamic library in which the symbols for [GonmeaFlutterBindings] can be found.
final DynamicLibrary _dylib = () {
  if (Platform.isMacOS || Platform.isIOS) {
    return DynamicLibrary.open('$_libName.framework/$_libName');
  }
  if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isLinux) {
    return DynamicLibrary.open('lib$_libName.so');
  }
  if (Platform.isWindows) {
    return DynamicLibrary.open('$_libName.dll');
  }
  throw UnsupportedError('Unknown platform: ${Platform.operatingSystem}');
}();

/// The bindings to the native functions in [_dylib].
final GonmeaFlutterBindings _bindings = GonmeaFlutterBindings(_dylib);


Please let me know if there's anything missing 
I have tried to directly use the generated header file in the C code and remove the autogenerated code and that doesn't seem to fix it
